# Accurately estimating non-linear relationship between two rasters

Tags: r, correlation

I am wanting to estimate the relationship between two rasters in R, but am having some trouble thinking through how I should do it. I am providing a toy example.

For example, suppose x (e.g. NDVI) is giving rise to y, which is a variable that sums up multiple species responses to x.

```
x = runif(100)
y = .25 + (2.5*x) + (-2.5 * I(x^2))
eps = rnorm(length(x),mean = 0, sd = .1)
y = as.vector(y + eps)
plot(x,y,ylim=c(0,1))
```

Here are the rasters from the data

```
y_rast = raster(nrow=10,ncol=10)
values(y_rast) = y

x_rast = y_rast
values(x_rast) = x
```

What is the best way to express the relationship between y and x? I was thinking of sampling, but would like to include some kind of estimation of significance (used loosely here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically the whole of statistics.

Given you simulated the data from a quadratic with a specified random noise, ideally you'd get that back as your "expression of the relationship between y and x", and your significance would be in the uncertainty in the parameters of the quadratic and the residual noise estimate, using standard likelihood-based techniques.

From real data you don't know what generated it, so you make a guess based on exploratory analysis or first principles given the science or a hypothesis you want to test. Looking at your x-y plot, I'd go "hmm looks quadratic" and fit a quadratic. My first assumption would also be uncorrelated independent errors of equal magnitude.

Once fitted there's "goodness of fit" methods to tell you where your model assumptions go wrong. You might discover your errors are spatially correlated, or are much larger in one area than another, in which case you have to reformulate your model with these discoveries and fit again.

So the short answer is "statistics". Propose a model for the mean relationship, (ooh, quadratic...), model for the error (ooh, uncorrelated independent errors), then fit, refine, until you can't disprove yourself any more. Goes for spatial data, longitudinal data, experimental data - anything. Its statistics.

Is that too broad? I don't want to say "fit a polynomial model using `glm(y~Poly(x, 2))` if your real data doesn't look like this. No, you need to go through the statistical process as outlined above.

Comment: Thanks. That is essentially what I was looking for. I am still trying to think of the best way to bootstrap a p-value, but maybe I just compare the model fits.

Comment: You can't have a p-value without a statistical hypothesis, and you can't have that without a probabilistic model, which is what model fits are.

Comment: That's true, my issue is that, as sample size increases the p-value decreases. So you can "cheat" and just sample more points. What I am thinking is that I am going to randomly sample points X times, and captures the parameter estimates. If the estimate doesn't cross 0 at 95% CI, should be fine.

Comment: I don't see what you original question has got to do with sampling. Why sample? Why not use all your data?

Comment: I wouldn't want to use all the points because of the relationship between p-values and sample size, and the spatial autocorrelation that comes with using all the points. I wouldn't necessarily call out someone that does it, I just don't feel comfortable doing it.

Comment: Throwing away data and ignoring spatial autocorrelation, when you could use all the data and look at modelling the spatial autocorrelation, should be the thing that makes you uncomfortable. If you feel uncomfortable because you don't know how to do something, that's the point that you consult a mentor, supervisor, or other professional who could direct you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are planning on stating and testing a hypothesis from a optimal non-linear estimate but, you can fit a non-linear functional form and derive a confidence interval using a local polynomial regression (or a spline). The `loess.boot` function in spatialEco should do the trick. Since it is a semi-paramteric approach, autocorrelation effects should be negligible.

```
library(raster)
library(spatialEco)
    
x = runif(100)
y = 0.25 + (2.5*x) + (-2.5 * I(x^2))
eps = rnorm(length(x),mean = 0, sd = 0.1)
y = as.vector(y + eps)

yr <- raster(matrix(y, nrow=10,ncol=10))
xr <- raster(matrix(x, nrow=10,ncol=10))
```

Here we bootstrap our our Local Polynomial Regression (LOESS) with p=999 for a 95% confidence region. There is a plot method for loess.boot and the fit and CI's are in the x$fit object.

```
( s <- loess.boot(xr[],yr[], 999) )
  plot(s, pch=20)
    head(s$fit)
```

[image: loess bootstrap CI's]

I should add an exact estimate output option to the function but, currently you have to use the predict function. You can pull the span parameter from the bootstrap object.

```
e <- raster(matrix(stats::predict(stats::loess(xr[] ~ yr[], 
            span=s$span),newdata = data.frame(xr[], yr[])),
            nrow=10, ncol=10))
  plot(e)
```

[image: non-linear spatial estimate]